# How to pinch two-finger rotate an object for Instagram stories on BlueStacks

Tags: bluestacks

I'd like to be able to rotate objects in Instagram Stories like text labels, locations, gifs, etc. Pinch zoom works by CTRL+Mouse Middle Button scroll up/down but I can't figure out how to pinch rotate objects with a keyboard or mouse hotkey. This is on a desktop without a touchscreen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late but: I have the same problem here in 2023. Now I figured out a strange workaround.
Just before zoom, HOLD the left mouse click then do the CTRL+Scroll up/down and move your mouse left or right horizontally.
This will change de zoom in/out too but don't mind with it, just flip the way you want and after that, you can zoom the size you wish to with the usual way CTRL+Scroll Up/Down without moving the mouse left or right horizontally.